# How to sum data within the same month?

Tags: excel, date, sum

I have a set of data which look like this:

```
     A         B      C
1| Date       | Value | Sum
2| 2014/08/03     10
3| 2014/08/02     7
4| 2014/08/01     5     todo
5| 2014/07/03     6
6| 2014/07/02     2
7| 2014/07/01     6     todo
8| 2014/06/03     1
9| 2014/06/02     4
10|2014/06/01     3     todo
```

Each cell on the Sum column has this part of code (will be autocompleted by dragging it down): `IF(MONTH($A2)=MONTH($A3);"";"todo")`
This would result in displaying text at each month's last line. The "todo" part would be replaced with code, which counts all values within the same month of "each last line", what would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(MONTH(A2)=MONTH(A3),"",SUM($B$1:B2)-SUM($C$1:C1))
```

and copy down

For your example:

[image]